# Searching Salesforce metadata using Visual Studio Code

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata

Is it possible to do key word metadata search using the Visual Studio Code Extensions similarly to Force IDE with Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean inside the files ? Check, cntrl + shift + F. It will also give you option for Match with case, whole word and *